# Symfony : How to use permission / groups with sfGuardAuth

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, sfdoctrineguard

I just saw that there is no so much documentation about sfGuardAuth groups and permission.

I have a permission named : moderator
I have 3 groups : full_time / half_time / quarter_time

In my backend (symfony 1.4 / doctrine), I have 5 modules
Only these two have to be visible for this : [st_job / st_offers ...].

**Generic rule** :
I want that the moderator can edit an offer but **NEVER delete it**

**Specific rule** :
I want that a full_time moderator can only see/edit full_time jobs or full_time offers
Same with half_time moderator can only see/edit half time jobs / offers ....

I didn't find after research how to do that ? I only manage to create my groups / permission on the backend and that's all.
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in reading the following:
http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfGuardPluginExtraDocumentation

Should give you a good idea of how to interact with the plugin to accomplish what you are trying to do.

A typical usage, is that upon a successful login, you check the user's role, and activate/deactivate options on your webpage accordingly.